# Using document.querySelector()

Tags: javascript, html

I have this js script:

```
<script>
  var checking_for_user = <%- JSON.stringify(overwrite) %> ;
  if (checking_for_user) {
   console.log('I reached here.');
   document.querySelector('.msg .text-center').innerHTML='User does not exist! Please go back to the <a href="/index">Index Page</a>';
  }
</script>
```

And below the script, i have this HTML code:

```
<div class="msg">
  <h1 class="text-center">
    There was an error. Please go back to the <a href="/index">Index Page</a>
  </h1>
</div>
```

The `checking_for_user variable` is from a Node.js response.
The code manages to reach the `console.log('I reached here.');` but the HTML doesn't change.

The `document.querySelector()` line does not work.
I tried even simpler parameters to `document.querySelector()` (just a string - no hyperlink) but it failed as well.

Anyone has a clue on what i am doing wrong here?

Comment: Are you getting an error in the JavaScript console that says you can't set a property of null?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The script you wrote will execute before the document is fully loaded, so `querySelector` will not find anything. If you put the script after the HTML, it should work as expected.